# MySQL data is visible in Toad Edge but not in CLI

Tags: mysql, mariadb, command-line-interface, toad

In a MySQL database called `rest_api` data is visible when looking at the `mobiles` table using the Toad Edge GUI:

[image]

[image]

However, according to the CLI there is no data in this table:
[image]

These 6 rows of data were added to the table using Toad Edge.

As an experiment, I added a row using the CLI and here is the result:
[image]

Interestingly enough, Toad Edge sees all the rows:
[image]

Why does the CLI not see the 6 rows that were added using the Toad Edge GUI?

**Edit #1-**
Here is the table definition of `mobiles`:
[image]

**Edit #2 -**
Another row has been added to the `mobiles` table via the CLI.  When Toad Edge is closed, then reopened, it only sees the 2 rows that were added by the CLI:

[image]

**Edit #3 -**
This is occurring on a Windows 10 OS.  XAMPP is installed on this machine and MySQL is part of the XAMPP install.

Comment: Check for `VIEWs`, odd `GRANTs`, other connections, magic incantations, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the AutoCommit was set to OFF in the lower right hand corner of the app:

[image]

Double clicking on it toggled it to be ON.  After that, it worked normally.  As in, when data was inserted into the table using a script in Toad Edge, a query in the CLI against the same table showed that the data was there.

[image]